# Maximum-Entropy Method deconvolution implementation?

Tags: optics, astronomy, software, image-processing

I am looking for an implementation of the Maximum Entropy Method for image deconvolution, ideally in MATLAB or Mathematica.

I'm trying to reconstruct an image from fringe visibilities, as is often done in aperture-masking interferometric astronomy, but I have only found minimal pseudocode in the literature.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/cemcen/maxent-matlab is what you are looking for